# How to extract postcode/digits from one column and put it in to another column in SQL Oracle 9i

Tags: sql, regex, substring, trim, oracle9i

Table `ADRESSES` contains columns `[ ID, STREET, TOWN, POSTCODE,COUNTRY ]`.

Hot to make statement in Oracle 9i database:

if column `COUNTRY` contains string `'UK'`, and `POSTCODE` is empty but column `TOWN` starts with post code (digits in format xxxxx or xx-xxx), then move postal code to column `POSTCODE` and strip post code from column `TOWN`.

Comment: Can you please add some samlpe data, and wanted output?

Comment: You should really show us what you've tried and why it didn't work, as well as providing sample data and expected results. We're here to help you, not do all the work for you.

Comment: @dawciobiel - if you get ORA-00904 rather than ORA-00920 (invalid relational operator) from Gordon's regex/left code then you're not really using Oracle 9i, so can you update and re-tag the question with the actual version you're using, while adding the sample data etc.?

Comment: No, i cant, becouse im using another database right now than question is. In other words solution should work on v9i - and there are no regular expressions

Comment: By digits do you mean numerical digits? Postal codes in the UK generally don't have that format. And the official ISO country code for the United Kingdom is `GBR` (alpha-3) or `GB` (alpha-2).

Comment: David Faber@ yes i know, it's like KT6-6RL for example, i was living in UK there for a while. I typed this post with "CONTURY='UK'", but it was only an example.

Comment: David Faber@ In my question 'digits' are characters [0-9]. But i have no idea why statment with 'select (..) where (...) TOWN like '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]%' (...)" doesnt work.

Comment: @dawciobiel - because `like` only recognises the `%` and `_` wildcards, it doesn't recognise any regular expression syntax; that's why a separate `regexp_like` was added in 10g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are two sql statements, one to select, and see the impact of the update statement, and the update statement. Back up your tables before you run any updates and always test that the update is doing what you expect by running it as a select statement first.

Note: I made the assumption that you want to keep the postcode in the format it was originally entered. eg if it was entered as xxxxx it will be saved as xxxxx and if it was entered as xx-xxx it will be saved as xx-xxx.

Check to see what the update statement will do:

```
select ID, STREET, TOWN, POSTCODE, COUNTRY, 
case when substr(TOWN, 3, 1) = '-' like '%-%' then trim(substr(TOWN,7, length(TOWN)-6)) else trim(substr(TOWN,6, length(TOWN)-5)) end as NEW_TOWN,
case when substr(TOWN, 3, 1) = '-' like '%-%' then substr(TOWN, 1, 6) else substr(TOWN, 1, 5) end as NEW_POSTCODE--Assumes you want to keep the dash if it exists
from ADDRESSES
where COUNTRY like'%UK%' --contains string UK
and trim(POSTCODE) is null -- postcode is empty
and (
    length(trim(translate(substr(TOWN, 1, 5), '0123456789', ' '))) is null -- town starts with xxxxx digits
    or
    (length(trim(translate(substr(TOWN, 1, 2)||substr(TOWN,4,3, '0123456789', ' '))))  and  substr(TOWN, 3, 1) = '-') -- town starts with xx-xxx digits
    )
;
```

If you are satisfied, run the update statement.

```
update ADDRESSES
set
TOWN = case when substr(TOWN, 3, 1) = '-' like '%-%' then trim(substr(TOWN,7, length(TOWN)-6)) else trim(substr(TOWN,6, length(TOWN)-5)) end,
POSTCODE = case when substr(TOWN, 3, 1) = '-' like '%-%' then substr(TOWN, 1, 6) else substr(TOWN, 1, 5) end --Assumes you want to keep the dash if it exists
from ADDRESSES
where COUNTRY like'%UK%' --contains string UK
and trim(POSTCODE) is null -- postcode is empty
and (
    length(trim(translate(substr(TOWN, 1, 5), '0123456789', ' '))) is null -- town starts with xxxxx digits
    or
    (length(trim(translate(substr(TOWN, 1, 2)||substr(TOWN,4,3, '0123456789', ' '))))  and  substr(TOWN, 3, 1) = '-') -- town starts with xx-xxx digits
    )
;
```

I hope this will at least serve as a starting point.

Comment: Well, thx anyway. Im not able to test that answer any longer. But i will 'accept' it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have O9i to test this either so I suspect my answer is going to be useless but I though I could try and did this just for kicks. I hope the following will give you or someone a starting point. The following seam to work in postgresql 9.3 :-)

```
create table addresses(
    id int,
    street varchar(255),
    town varchar(255),
    postcode varchar(6),
    country varchar(3)
);

insert into addresses values (1, '1', '11-111 dupa jasio1','', 'UK');
insert into addresses values (2, '2', '22222 dupa jasio2','', 'UK');
insert into addresses values (3, '3', '33-333 dupa jasio3','', 'UK');
insert into addresses values (4, '4', '44444 dupa jasio4','', 'UK');
insert into addresses values (5, '5', '55555 dupa jasio5','', 'PL');

dawid=# select * from addresses ;
 id | street |        town        | postcode | country 
----+--------+--------------------+----------+---------
  1 | 1      | 11-111 dupa jasio1 |          | UK
  2 | 2      | 22222 dupa jasio2  |          | UK
  3 | 3      | 33-333 dupa jasio3 |          | UK
  4 | 4      | 44444 dupa jasio4  |          | UK
  5 | 5      | 55555 dupa jasio5  |          | PL
```

query to update postcodes looking like 12345

```
update addresses set 
postcode=substring(town, '^([0-9]{5})'),
town=substring(town, '^[0-9]{5}\s(.*)')
where country like '%UK%' and 
(postcode is null or postcode='') and 
town ~ E'^[0-9]{5} ';
```

query to update postcodes looking like 12-123

```
update addresses set 
postcode=substring(town, '^([0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{3})'),
town=substring(town, '^[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{3}\s([\w\d\-\s]+)')
where country like '%UK%' and 
(postcode is null or postcode='') and 
town ~ E'^[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{3} ';
```

outcome

```
dawid=# select * from addresses ;
 id | street |       town        | postcode | country 
----+--------+-------------------+----------+---------
  5 | 5      | 55555 dupa jasio5 |          | PL
  2 | 2      | dupa jasio2       | 22222    | UK
  4 | 4      | dupa jasio4       | 44444    | UK
  1 | 1      | dupa jasio1       | 11-111   | UK
  3 | 3      | dupa jasio3       | 33-333   | UK
```

Comment: Well, thx anyway. Im not able to test that answer any longer as well.

Comment: You're still using regular expressions, which are not supported in 9i.